# Nested div and 'cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null' error

Tags: javascript, html

This error is typically due to the element being referenced before the DOM has fully loaded. As such, I've made sure to only run the required script once the window has loaded.

Interestingly, if the getElementById() call is to a standalone `<div>`, i.e. a non-nested `<div>`, the innerHTML executes as desired. This therefore demonstrates that all the required naming conventions etc. are correct.

The code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function(window, document, undefined) {
        window.onload = function() {
            google.charts.load('current', {
            packages:['corechart'],
            callback: drawChart
        });

        function drawChart() {

            var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
            div1.innerHTML = 'DIV1';

            var div1_header = document.getElementById('div1_header');
            div1_header.innerHTML = "DIV1 HEADER";
        }
        };
    })(window, window.document);

</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="div" id="div1">
        <div class="div_header" id="div1_header"></div>
    </div>
<body>
```

As stated above, if I modify the code to the below, it works as expected:

```
<div class="div" id="div1"></div>
<div class="div_header" id="div1_header"></div>
```

How can the fact that the div1_header is nested be resulting in a 'null' error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting  `div1.innerHTML = 'DIV1';` you are `deleting` entire `innerHTML` of `div1 (including div1_header)` and replacing it with `DIV1 text`, so change that line into:

```
var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
div1.innerHTML += 'DIV1';
```

Comment: I never would have picked that up, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

The following line is replacing the innerHTML of div1 with 'DIV1'.

```
div1.innerHTML = 'DIV1';
```

As a result div1_header no longer exists when you attempt to set its innerHTML.

Comment: As per my comment below, I would never have suspected that. Thanks for pointing that out!